# Eclipse Juno red minimize and maximize buttons on Linux

Tags: java, button, minimize, eclipse-juno, maximize

I'm running Eclipse Juno 4.2.0 on Linux with Gtk version 1.2.10 and I'm having a following graphics "bug" in the GUI: All the minimize and maximize buttons have a red background colour. In other words, minimize and maximize icons are inside little red squares.

I'm not administering the system, where I'm running the Eclipse, so updating the Gtk is not very easy if even possible. How to fix the problem?

Edit:
I'm using Eclipse through VNC.

Answer (score 4):

On RHEL 5 / CentOS 5, the red boxes went away when I changed VNC's color depth to 24-bit. For example, with the standard VNC server:

```
vncserver :10 -geometry 1280x960 -depth 24
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is a known bug in Eclipse ([Bug 374985](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=374985)) since March 2012.

There are various duplicates in distribution such as this FC17 [Bug 815941](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=815941).

What you can do now: Install Ubuntu 12.04: it will work both in KDE and Gnome, normal desktop or VNC.

Unfortunately in Centos 5, red squares will keep appearing both in Gnome and KDE.

Comment: Thanks for response , i have already came across the links and strange about this error :)

Comment: Thanga if anyone knew they would fix the bug. It is officially open in Eclipse end RedHat. Not sure what more do you want.

Answer (score 1):

It also works fine with Linux Mint. I have been using it for months without any issues.

Edit: I am though using the version for c/c++, but i doubt this would have any impact since yours is java

Comment: Thanks for response , i does not understand  why its not working in my system:)

Comment: Which distribution are you on? At work i am using mint 64, at home laptop i had ubuntu 11 now upgraded to 12.04 (x64) and both have Juno running fine. Oh just saw the CentOS mention.

Comment: same distribution of eclipse mentioned in the posts:) CentOS :)